# How to generate table from array?

Tags: reactjs

I have data in this format:

```
data = [{synonyms: [apple, pie, cookie], value: "taste"},
        {synonyms: [apple, pie, cookie], value: "taste"},
        {synonyms: [apple, pie, cookie], value: "taste"}]
```

I need to generate table with values as column names and synonyms as columns.

Comment: Could you provide a better explanation for how you would like the table to be structured?

Comment: @Jezpoz I need the table like that      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnvT97X2rZGpx6hyMUkw89xvOoRgbL-ZAcqLSO-JVoo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jezpoz also there can be any number of elements in the array "sinonims" and any {}  parts

Answer (score 1):

I see that an answer was posted before mine. But it's always good to have several inputs.

[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwv4r1xopn)

Code-dump:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" },
  { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" },
  { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" }
];

function App() {
  const renderTableHeader = () => {
    const headers = data.map(entry => entry.value);
    return headers.map(header => <td>{header}</td>);
  };

  const renderTableContent = () => {
    const contents = data.map(entry => entry.synonyms);

    return contents.map(content => (
      <tr>
        {content.map(synonym => (
          <td>{synonym}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>{renderTableHeader()}</thead>
        <tbody>{renderTableContent()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `map()` on data you can pass values to the table. This is the working solution.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let data = [
      { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" },
      { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" },
      { synonyms: ["apple", "pie", "cookie"], value: "taste" }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th>{item.value}</th>
                {item.synonyms.map((syn, index) => {
                  return <td key={index}>{syn}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr td {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: this is a good answer but I fell like @Jezpoz made a more organized and clean one